# Drag and drop TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, winrt-xaml, uwp

I have a drag and drop interface in my Universal Windows App, where the user can add a textbox to the image, and drag and scale it around, as if it was a textbox in MSPaint, but it can be edited after it is placed, by double-tapping it.

I have implemented this as such:

`textBox.LostFocus` sets `textBox.IsReadOnly = true;`
`textBox.DoubleTapped` sets `IsReadOnly` back to false, so that it can drag around.
`textBox.ManipulationDelta` moves the textBox around.

Now I have the problem that the `textBox` has this rubberbanding effect going on, and that this blocks the manipulation event.

Is there a way to disable this? Or can I for example say when the mouse clicks (or finger or whatever), that it should start the manipulation event?

Code for a new `TextBox`:

```
private TextBox CreateManipulativeTextBox(string text)
{
    var textBox = new TextBox
    {
        Text = text,
        Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0)),
        BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, 0, 0, 0)),
        Width = 150,
        Height = 50,
        ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX | ManipulationModes.TranslateY | ManipulationModes.Scale,
        RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform()
    };

    // Doubletap gives edit possibility, tap outside loses editability
    textBox.LostFocus += TextBoxOnLostFocus;
    textBox.DoubleTapped += TextBoxOnDoubleTapped;

    // Add manipulation events
    textBox.ManipulationStarted += OnManipulationStarted;
    textBox.ManipulationDelta += OnManipulationDelta;
    textBox.ManipulationCompleted += OnManipulationCompleted;

    return textBox;
}
```

Code for focus and defocus:

```
private void TextBoxOnDoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs doubleTappedRoutedEventArgs)
{
    (sender as TextBox).IsReadOnly = false;
}

private void TextBoxOnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
    (sender as TextBox).IsReadOnly = true;
}
```

Code for manipulation:

```
private void OnManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is TextBox)
        (sender as TextBox).IsReadOnly = true;
    ((FrameworkElement)sender).Opacity = 0.6;
}

private void OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var frameworkElement = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    var transform = (CompositeTransform)frameworkElement.RenderTransform;

    // LEFT-RIGHT bounds
    if (e.Delta.Translation.X < 0) // Going left
    {
        if (DrawingArea.ActualWidth / 2 + (transform.TranslateX + e.Delta.Translation.X) - frameworkElement.ActualWidth / 2 > 0)
        {
            // Staying inside, apply translation
            transform.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        }
        else
        {
            // Trying to go outside, because scale sucks to work with, move image back inside
            transform.TranslateX = frameworkElement.ActualWidth / 2 - DrawingArea.ActualWidth / 2;
        }
    }
    else // Going right
    {
        if (DrawingArea.ActualWidth / 2 - (transform.TranslateX + e.Delta.Translation.X) +
            frameworkElement.ActualWidth * (0.5 - transform.ScaleX) > 0)
        {
            // Staying inside, apply translation
            transform.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        }
        else
        {
            // Trying to go outside, because scale sucks to work with, move image back inside
            transform.TranslateX = frameworkElement.ActualWidth * (0.5 - transform.ScaleX) + DrawingArea.ActualWidth / 2;
        }
    }

    // UP-DOWN bounds
    if (e.Delta.Translation.Y < 0) // Going up
    {
        if (DrawingArea.ActualHeight / 2 + (transform.TranslateY + e.Delta.Translation.Y) - frameworkElement.ActualHeight / 2 >
            0)
        {
            // Staying inside, apply translation
            transform.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
        }
        else
        {
            // Trying to go outside, because scale sucks to work with, move image back inside
            transform.TranslateY = frameworkElement.ActualHeight / 2 - DrawingArea.ActualHeight / 2;
        }
    }
    else // Going down
    {
        if (DrawingArea.ActualHeight / 2 - (transform.TranslateY + e.Delta.Translation.Y) +
            frameworkElement.ActualHeight * (0.5 - transform.ScaleY) > 0)
        {
            // Staying inside, apply translation
            transform.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
        }
        else
        {
            // Trying to go outside, because scale sucks to work with, move image back inside
            // transform.TranslateY = image.ActualHeight*(0.5 - transform.ScaleY) + DrawingArea.ActualHeight/2;

            // Dragging down, remove image
            DrawingArea.Children.Remove(frameworkElement);
        }
    }

    // Only allow scaling when both dimensions are smaller than the drawingarea
    if (frameworkElement.ActualHeight * (transform.ScaleY * e.Delta.Scale) < DrawingArea.ActualHeight &&
        frameworkElement.ActualWidth * (transform.ScaleX * e.Delta.Scale) < DrawingArea.ActualWidth)
    {
        transform.ScaleX *= e.Delta.Scale;
        transform.ScaleY *= e.Delta.Scale;
    }
}

private void OnManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((FrameworkElement)sender).Opacity = 1;
}
```

**EDIT:** This only happens with touch, when the mouse drags the item around it works.

Comment: Could you post some source code to see exactly what you have done?

Comment: @LeonBohmann edited my question

Comment: And the DragEnter/ DragLeave event doesn't work for you?

Comment: @BionicCode What should I do with those events? I don't see how that could help.

Comment: You could replace the manipulation event which may be responsible for the odd drag behavior.

Comment: @BionicCode I removed all references to the manipulationevents and the `TextBox` still does the weird behaviour. Also, `DragEnter`/`DragLeave` doesn't get called on my `TextBox`.

Comment: okay, sorry. Have you tried to set "IsManipulationEnabled" on your TextBox or whatever youre trying to move to true? Just asking...

Comment: There is no `IsManipulationEnabled` on `TextBox`. This code works for dragging with mouse, so I know this works. It's only for dragging with touch that this rubberbanding occurs.

Comment: Sadly this is Universal Windows :( It is not available there.

Comment: ehem, sorry. Didn't see it. Of course the tag of your post is showing this...soory for wasting your time...